# No errors encountered and script was returned as PASS, but pyautogui is not working (Robot Framework using PyCharm)

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, pyautogui

I am having an issue with using pyautogui.

```
Library             Selenium2Library
Library             String
Library             pyautogui

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Press enter key
    Press  'enter'


C:\Tools\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat test.robot
==============================================================================
Scenario: Press enter key                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It returned as PASS but nothing happened. It did not perform the **press** command. Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sent **ENTER** key .Try below code

```
 Press Key     ${somelocator}      \\13
```

[Here some document how to use Press Key](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Press%20Key)